# A summation manipulation

Tags: generating-functions, recursion

I want to solve a generating function - recursive sequence problem and I am stuck one step before the solution where I want to combine the three sums in order to extract a formula for $a_n$.

$$G(x) = 4\Sigma_{n=0}^\infty 3^nx^n - 4\Sigma_{n=1}^\infty 3^nx^n + \Sigma_{n=2}^\infty 3^nx^n$$

A hint would be great since I know I am close but I can't see the way to get from the above to a format like

$$G(x) = \Sigma_{n=0}^\infty a(c+...+d) 3^nx^n $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $(a_0,a_1,\dots)$ denote $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n3^nx^n$. There are three terms in $G(x)$; from left to right they are
$$(4,4,4,4,4,\dots)$$
$$(0,-4,-4,-4,-4,\dots)$$
$$(0,0,1,1,1,\dots)$$
They sum to the following sequence:
$$(4,0,1,1,1,\dots)$$
i.e.
$$G(x)=4+\sum_{n=2}^\infty3^nx^n=4+\frac{(3x)^2}{1-3x}$$